# Getting "Internal server error" when AWS API gateway was called with Lambda integration with java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Learning AWS through online.
Similar questions were asked but What I did was Lambda with java8.0 combination.
(Note: lambda+python worked for me). What I did is below.

1.Created a Lambda function with java 8.0 and
2.Uploaded code as jar(thanks to pom.xml)   code is below:
3.Added API Gateway from designer in lambda screen -Made it open.
4.Generated API url pasted in browser then I got error "{"message": "Internal server error"}"
5.In python(python use case which is working) I returned as below then it worked

But not working for java. Could you please provided links if any or answer.

Python code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
print("In lambda handler")

resp = {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
    "body": "My Name"
}

return resp
```

Java Code:
   package test1;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class TestLambda implements RequestHandler {

```
    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);

        return "Hello from Lambda";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found answer , Please find the below updated class which worked for me

```
@Override
    public ServerlessOutput handleRequest(ServerlessInput arg0, Context arg1) {
         Map<String, String> headers= new HashMap<String,String>();
         headers.put("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        ServerlessOutput output= new ServerlessOutput();
         output.setStatusCode(200);
         output.setBody("Hello From First lambda with java");
         output.setHeaders(headers);
        return output;
    }
```

Let me summarize the points.

1. Create a lambda function in AWS with API gateway designer and  Runtime as java 8.0
2. Design API and get API URL which will call your lambda function.
3. create a class as above and generate the jar and upload.
4. Use the API url in your html/jsp to get response from your java file.

I can help if anyone trying this combination (aws +lambda+java 8.0+API)